# Eclipse Refactor > Rename disabled

Tags: java, eclipse-luna

I have a project that I've been using Refactor > Rename quite a bit on, and all of a sudden the shortcut (Alt-Shift-R) stops working, instead bringing up the Run menu as if the shortcut didn't exist. Rename is missing from the right-click refactor menu, and is disabled in the menu bar. I've tried restarting Eclipse, but the issue persists. All refactoring actions in all menus are disabled except "inline". What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you select the file in the "Package Explorer" view.

Not the "Project Explorer" view, 
Not the "Navigator" view, 
Not the (insert whichever redundant file-view views I've omitted) view,
but only, and for no compellingly good reason, 
the Package Explorer view.

This will enable the disabled Refactor options.

Comment: This question is really old, back before I started using IntelliJ. I'm not sure if I ever fixed it, since I got a new computer since then.